# How do I make Jupyter catagorical stacked bar chart scale to 100% using multi variables

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

My table is below. I like to make a catagorical stacked bar chart, scaled to 100% using the three variables Cluster_1, Cluster_2 and Cluster_3.

[image]

Can you please help me with it?
Best regards
Farshid

Comment: What have you tried? See [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html) or [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/stacked-and-percent-stacked-barplot/)? Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially under 'Help others reproduce the problem' where it states in bold "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**"

Comment: Can you write a code for this table?

Comment: "Can you write a code for this table?" That's not how this site works. ... If you use Pandas or [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), it should be able to read a tsv or csv file made from that data.

Comment: I have tried a lot. Probably, Python is not able to perform such a task I think!

Comment: Hmmm...I don't know what you tried. And I don't know what task you are saying Python is not able to perform. If it is anything you described here then I doubt that.  Python is very capable. I like using Pandas to manage handling tabular data.

Comment: First it must add the three Clusters (1,2 and3) to each other to get the sum. Then it has to devide the bar chart in three proportionally to the amount of the Clusters for each name.

Comment: It can do it but it can't put them on top of each other in a bar chart.

Comment: That is what you should search or post about. Your post didn't indicate that you could get this far. You can always use toy data that you provide along with actual code for how far you got. And it isn't particular to Jupyter, although always best to mention that in case you are missing something special others know about. However, this seems like a Python issue. You'd have the same issue if running Python via a script.